# Recursively delete empty folders with verbose output

Tags: bash, scripting, shell-scripting, find

This should be fairly simple, but I am not sure what i'm missing.

I'd like to **recursively** delete empty directories, and get an output for what's being deleted, this command works for sure, but I just can't print the actions of -excec verbosely.

`while [ -n "$(find . -depth -type d -empty -exec rm -v -rf {} +)" ]; do :; done`

by **recursively** I mean, I want to keep deleting empty folders, until there's no other empty folder.

```
$ tree .
.
├── empty
│   └── empty
│       └── empty
└── non-emty
    └── ko
```

this item will only remove one empty folder in the tree

```
$ find . -depth -type d -empty -exec rmdir -v {} +
rmdir: removing directory, `./empty/empty'
```

Comment: I worry about the logic of this -- is a directory empty if it only contains directories that are empty?  Also -- as far as logging the output -- whenever I do something like this that has the potential to wreck a whole bunch of stuff, I have it output the command it would run but not actually run the command itself.  Then, if I actually want to run those commands I can just run the output like a shell script.

Comment: you right, i have the wrong verbiage, it's not quite empty. let me change that. it has nothing to do with logic, lol there's a problem, keep deleting empty directories until there are none left. I try to  solve.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't need the while loop and you should use rmdir -p to remove the empty parents

```
find . -depth -type d -empty -exec rmdir -v -p {} + 
rmdir: removing directory, `./1/3'
rmdir: removing directory, `./1'
rmdir: removing directory, `.'
rmdir: failed to remove directory `.': Invalid argument
rmdir: removing directory, `./2/3'
rmdir: removing directory, `./2'
rmdir: failed to remove directory `./2': Directory not empty
```

The reason you don't see the output with your command is that you are running it in a subshell `$(...)` but doing nothing with the returned output you could put an echo before the subsell to print out what it returns

```
echo $(find . -depth -type d -empty -exec rmdir -v -p {} +)
rmdir: removing directory, `./1/3' rmdir: removing directory, `./1' rmdir: removing directory, `.' rmdir: removing directory, `./2/3' rmdir: removing directory, `./2'
```

Comment: **recursively** like This does work on one line, but I want to keep deleting empty folders until there's no true empty folder.

Comment: @kmassada: use `rmdir -p`

Answer (score 0):

With `find`, on both Linux and MacOS, you have the `-delete` option. It already implies `-depth`. And for verbose output, you can add `-print`. So it's just :

```
find . -type d -empty -delete -print
```